# I want to change of Bluetooth pairing timeout in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source, android-bluetooth

I want to change Bluetooth pairing timeout but I didn't find the relevant variable in AOSP 10 source tree. I found some answers but they are changing it via ADB shell/script but I don't want to use this method. I need to change relevant places and re-build the source.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bluetooth Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-3/) the timeout has a fixed value of 30 seconds. So you may not be able to change this value.
See also chapter *"Vol 3: Host / Part H: Security Manager Specification / 3 Security Manager Protocol / 3.4 SMP timeout"*

Comment: Sir, I found a file (ScanManager.java) that manages scan timeouts and intervals. The path to this file is: "$(ANDROID_ROOT)/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/ScanManager.java"
I think this class may be related to my problem. [ScanManager.java](http://aospxref.com/android-10.0.0_r47/xref/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/ScanManager.java#474)
What is your opinion?